# Android service in library

Tags: android, service

i created a library with a service in that i want to be able to bind to in more than one apk.

This is in my libraries manifest

```
<service class=".service.MyService" android:permission="com.wissen.permission.MY_SERVICE_PERMISSION">
<intent-filter>
<action android:value="com.wissen.testApp.service.MY_SERVICE" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

and this is in my apk manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.wissen.permission.MY_SERVICE_PERMISSION"></uses-permission>
```

and i of course added the lib to the apk. i keep on getting service not found (warning). What am i doing wrong.

i bind it this way

```
bindService(new Intent("com.wissen.testApp.service.MY_SERVICE"), conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**Solution:**
I created aidl for these and its working fine now.

Comment: I created aidl for these and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service must be a remote service. You should create an *.aidl (interface to your service) and start it in it's own process.
You can read about it here: [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: No, it does not need to be a remote service to be used from an Android library project. That would be needed only if the service were in a totally separate application.

Comment: @CommonsWare What would be another method of declaring a service in a library?

Comment: @Bryan: I do not understand your question, sorry. You might want to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you can explain in greater detail your concerns.

Answer (score 27):

The service needs to be specified in the Manifest for your application, not the library.

Comment: This should work fine. I think eventually `<service>` elements and the like defined in a library will be automatically included in host project, but I don't think that's there yet. Just copy the `<service>` element from the library's manifest and put it in the host application.

Comment: I add it but the problem with that i have to define in both apk's( manifest) and then when i bind it in one and try binding it in another it creates a new instance it does not use the same instance of the service or it looked like it. i put a log in the create and it called it twice also i tryed calling a set i have in my binding object and it does not reflect if call the get from the second apk so it must be creating two instances.

Comment: isn't there some more elegant solution than asking developers to add service in their app manifest?

Comment: Manifest merging will now put a service declared in the library project into the application's manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

I created aidl for these and its working fine now.

Comment: are you writing blog or will you share your code ..I am facing error 
like stub.interface not found...