# Android external Service from a library (AAR, not Shared Service)

Tags: android, service, dependencies, aar

I am trying to create an Android Library containing a simple service. For example:

```
public class BasicService extends Service {
    public BasicService() {
        Log.d("I", "work");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I start the service the following way:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BasicService.class));
```

The service is compiled into an AAR file and after adding that to an application I get a ClassNotFoundException.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nl.company.example.library.Services.BasicService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/nl.example.aartest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I don't need to bind a service as the application does not have to communicate with the service. I also don't need an aidl interface as I don't want to share the service with other apps. I know I need to declare the service at the application side (not library) so I did that the following way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nl.company.example.exampleApp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:settings... >
    <service
        android:name="nl.company.example.library.Services.BasicService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the manifest of my library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.company.example.library" >
    <application/>
</manifest>
```

I've done some research at Stackoverflow/Google and I wasn't able to find an answer to my problem.

[Android service in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394121/android-service-in-library)

Also tried different ways of starting the service (on action etc.) but no good so far.

All help is welcome and my apologies if I made an evil duplicate question.

Comment: There is a mismatch between your classname `BasicService` and the service you actually start `SimpleService`. Might that be the issue?
Just tried this in a test repo and seems to be working fine. I don't declare the service in the manifest of my library, but I do declare it in the manifest of my application. I start the service in exactly the same way as you do and include the library via a local aar.

Comment: Hello jmols, sorry this was a mistake with making the issue anonymous. Also added the libraries manifest. Hope you are able to help:)

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. Autocomplete is working right? (That way we're sure the dependency is included correctly.) What version of the Gradle plugin are you using? I'm using  `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0`.

Comment: Autocomplete also working right that's why it's driving me nuts. And yes also using gradle version 1.3.0.

Comment: How do you include the `aar` file in your project? In what folder/repository is it stored?

Comment: I use IDE android studio. File->Project structure->New module(alt-insert)->import JAR/AAR package-> select correct AAR. Then I press module app and add the AAR to the dependencies. It will be added in the gradle of the app in the dependencies like this:     compile project(':mybeamlibrary-debug'). Then it is placed at the main folder of the project.

Comment: Tried to do the same here and everything is working like it should... If you upload a full project I can take a look?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0yfc53dnu8z4e2/TestOfAar.7z?dl=0

Comment: When I include your aar file into my project I get the same error, so I'm guessing its a library issue. Can you try adding a complete <application> element to your manifest? (containing theme and label) Also your `R.txt` seems to contain many elements of the support library (which are not included in your app), can you clean your project and build a new `aar`?

Comment: If I add theme I get duplicate theme exceptions: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:9:9-40
 is also present at [TestOfAar:mybeamlibrary-debug:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-47 value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat)
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override

Comment: Both done but doesn't work unfortunately:(

Comment: What is in the R.txt file if you uncompress the new `aar` file? Are there still references to the support lib?

Comment: Yes there still are, do I need to remove support lib from my lib?

Comment: The reason why I think this might be causing problems is because the file defines resources which are not packaged with the app. Maybe this causes a compilation issue of some sort? (my library doesn't include the support lib)

Comment: Even moving all classes to new library project results in the same..

Comment: Moving to the main app works, right? And if you include the module iso the `aar`?

Comment: What do you mean with "Moving to the main app works, right? And if you include the module iso the aar?". I succesfully removed the support lib but doesn't work either.

Comment: I can share the library with you if you want?

Comment: I mean merging your library with your main app, just to verify that the code actually works. What I would recommend is that you create a completely new project, with a library and an app. And then create the simplest prototype possible, just to get a similar setup like me working. Then you can re-add all your code from there. makes sense?

Comment: I am sorry for late response. Base seems to work I'll let you know more in secs..

Comment: Really curious as to what the issue actually is :)

Comment: First I thought it would be because I am missing empty constructor, still working on it. More info asap.

Comment: The problem is solved! The problem is using an interface from a sub-library dependency. Added that dependency to the application and it is working now. If I use a interface from a sub library it will just show class not found of the service while it is actually the interface that's not found. If I used an external class of the sub library the message suddenly was clear. Thanks for all your help! Please post this as answer and I will be happy to accept;)

Comment: Great, glad it is working for you now! Also very useful to know that `ClassNotFoundExceptions` work the way they do. (and can mask other interfaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BaseService was implementing an interface from another library which was not packaged with the `aar` file. This caused the application to crash right after starting on a device, because it couldn't resolve the dependency.

```
public class BaseService implements OtherLibraryInterface {
    ...
}
```

Instead of throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` for the `OtherLibraryInterface`, Android would throw exactly that exception for the `BaseService`. Which is very confusing and lead us to believe that there is something wrong with the Service.

Adding the OtherLibrary dependency explicitly as a dependency to the main application solved this issue.