# Do the notificationchannels need to be created multiple times?

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-channel

I've always wondered if the application must call `createNotificationChannel` on every startup or to have they created once on first use is guaranteed to be fine...

I ask that because many tutorials like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5394210/5679560 suggest to do that during `Application onCreate` which means every start of the app

But, unless there is a way for the user or other app, manually delete the channel, I could simple create these channels on first app run

what is the correct approach